# Accessing a csv file in python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I keep getting an "invalid keyword" error when i try to read from a csv file in python. Any ideas for a work around for this?

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/User_Name/PycharmProjects/untitled/car.py

Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"C:/Users/User_Name/PycharmProjects/untitled/car.py", line 122, in <module> d = handle_refugee_data.DataTable(csvformat="generic", data_directory="car2014", start_date="2013-12-01") File 
"C:\Users\User_Name\PycharmProjects\untitled\handle_refugee_data.py", line 78, in __init__ with open("%s/%s" % (data_directory, data_layout), newline='') as csvfile: 
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function 

Process finished with exit code 1
========================================================================
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: It looks like `open()` doesn't have such keyword: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open But this can be told for sure only after you'll post your code.

Comment: And for that matter: [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) is in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

`newline` is a valid keyword argument to `open()` [in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open), but not [in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open), which appears to be what you are using.

One solution, if possible, would be to execute the script with Python 3 instead. Alternatively, as pointed out by **@dhke** in the comments, you could use [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) instead, which does accept a `newline` keyword argument.

Of course, you could probably use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead, depending on your use case (which is not clear from the original question).

Comment: @dhke thanks for the tip! I will add it to the answer.